# Apache Camel - Bindy - CSV - Producer - Finishing each line with the separator

Tags: csv, apache-camel, bindy

I would like, while producing CSV files with bindy, to finish each line with the separator. 
My first thought was to search for a configuration annotation, which I could not find.

At the moment I am using a workaround, which consists of having a dummy-last-attribute in the CsvRecord-class.

Is there a more elegant way of doing that?

Thanks + regards.

Comment: Have you considered adding your separator in the CRLF parameter? E.g., if your separator is, say, a tab, your CRLF may look like `"\t\n"`

Comment: I did consider adding the separator to the crlf, yes. Still think that's a kind of workaround. Since if you change the separator you have to change that too + is not an out-of-the-box annotation like crlf="UNIX".